# Angular 2 executing method across all opened browsers

Tags: angular

I created a button and assigned (click) event to fire my `doSomthing()` method.

```
doSomething()
{
console.log("YOU CLICKED");
}
```

I tried to open chrome along with my FireFox and I noticed strange thing: Clicking the button from my FireFox firing the method on my chrome browser too! (and same opposite)

That means that clicking the button in chrome will make FireFox developer console show `"YOU CLICKED"`, and same in chrome!

Why clicking the button from one browser execute it in another too? and how I can fix it?

Comment: That's a feature of the server you're using.

Comment: What's this feature name?

Comment: BrowserSync . . . .. .